# Catch back button on a fragment conditionally

Tags: android, fragment, back-button

I have a fragment with several views in it. I want to catch the back button on it, so if a specific views in it is selected, just omit the button press and if that specific view is not selected, like any back button press do its job. I used the below code to catch the back button:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, paramViewGroup, false);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (fab.isSelected()) {
                    hideMenu();
                    fab.setSelected(!fab.isSelected());
                }
                // else
                //     How back button do its habitual job?
                //
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I change the code that the back button does its habitual job?

With current code, the back button never terminates the app in home page.

Comment: try `getActivity().onBackPressed;`

Comment: A simply answer is to call `onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity scope and call it from your `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Do your things.
}

public void method()
{
    onBackPressed();
}
```

If you want to add some complex logic in the `onBackPressed` method, just create another one with parameters.

```
public void myOnBackPressed(int param1, String param2)
{
    // Do your complex logic.
    onBackPressed();
}

public void method()
{
    myOnBackPressed(myInt, myString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, you set `return true`. It means you process back button, you don't want emit the back button ouside. 
You can call `onBackPressed()` in `onKey()` method to emit back button outside. Or you can process back button in `onBackPressed()` of fragment.